# Expo notification icon not showing

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

I have built an app using React Native (Reminder App) and i need it to show notification. That is working perfectly but when i receive a notification the icon shows as a small purple square. Below is an image of similar output found on google  [image: similar output found on google images]

Expected Output: Should show my icon on top left of notification

My current code in app.json is:

```
 "expo": {
"name": "Reminders",
"slug": "Reminders",
"version": "2.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon1.png",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash1.png",
  "resizeMode": "cover",
  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",

  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-notifications",
      {
        "icon": "./assets/icon1.png",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  ]
},

"notification": {
  "icon":"./assets/icon1.png",
  "color": "#7f2ee1"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon1.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "icon":"./assets/icon1.png",
  "package": "com.d99.reminders",
  "versionCode":4
},
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/icon1.png"
}
}
}
```

I followed the instructions on the official docs for expo-notifications but the issue remains.

Any idea on how to show my icon there?

edit: here is the icon [[icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHdOF.png)]

Comment: Add you icon file in question.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar the icon file is a simple png logo with white background seen as ./assets/icon1.png in the code above

Comment: @D99 have you found a solution for this?